# How can I set the default value in an Access form using a command button and VBA?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am working on a form that I need to change the default value for a control during run time without having to go into design mode. I need to use a command button and either VBA or a Macro. What will happen is when the user needs to change a location they are working with for an audit, they click on the button and get a prompt to change the location by scanning a barcode and then refresh the form so that it will display the new location.

I know it can be done, I did it with another database about 8 years ago, I just can't remember how I did it.

This is what I am trying to do. I am trying to keep it as simple as possible, since if something goes wrong I may not be the one that needs to fix it.

```vb
Me.Form.frmEntry.txtLocation.DefaultValue = InputBox("Please Enter A New Location", "Location Change")
Me.Refresh
```

I have tried this and several variations of it, as well as 6 days of searching various websites and can't quite find the hint that I am looking for.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultValue` is a *text*, so you need quotes - and the straight syntax:

```
Me!txtLocation.DefaultValue = """" & InputBox("Please Enter A New Location", "Location Change") & """"
```

Comment: You Sir are a Steely Eyed missile man. It never dawned on me that I was using too many quotes or to use the & to put them together. I will definitely be spending a lot more time on this site. I still have a lot to learn. I've realized over the years that, the more I learn, the more I have TOO learn. Thank very much for your help.